# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am having the following error while running my Spring Application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleController' defined in file [/home/john/Documents/Projects/lottery-api/target/classes/io/sunbits/lotteryapi/resources/RoleController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleService' defined in file [/home/john/Documents/Projects/lottery-api/target/classes/io/sunbits/lotteryapi/services/RoleService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract io.sunbits.lotteryapi.entities.User io.sunbits.lotteryapi.data.repository.ExtendedCrudRepository.findOne(java.lang.Long)! No property findOne found for type Role!
```

The application is pretty big, so I will copy paste you the code related to RoleController.class and maybe you can help me :).

**RoleController:**

```
    @CrossOrigin
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/roles",
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
        public class RoleController {

            private RoleService service;

        @Autowired
        public RoleController(RoleService service) {
            this.service = service;
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
        public ResponseEntity<?> search(
                @RequestParam(required = false) String name,
                @RequestParam(required = false) String description,
                @RequestParam(required = false) Boolean active,
                @RequestParam(value = "_page", defaultValue = "0", required = false) Integer page,
                @RequestParam(value = "_size", defaultValue = "25", required = false) Integer size,
                @RequestParam(value = "_sort", defaultValue = "-name", required = false) String sort) {

            Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size,
                    SortUtils.processSort(
                            sort,
                            new String[]{"name","description","active"}
                    ));

            Specification specification = RoleSpecification.genericSearchSpecification(name,description,active);

            Page<Role> roles = this.service.findAll(specification,pageable);
            PageInfo pageInfo = new PageInfo(roles);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new RestResponse<>(roles.getContent(),pageInfo));
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = {"", "/"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
        //@PreAuthorize("#oauth2.hasRole('create_item')")
        public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody Role role, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {

            if (result.hasErrors()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(result.getFieldErrors(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(this.service.create(role), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
        public ResponseEntity<?> find(@PathVariable Long id) {
            Role role = service.findOne(id);
            ApiPreconditions.assertNotNullOrEmpty(role, "Role not exists: " + id);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(role);
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
        public ResponseEntity<?> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Role role) {
            Role oldRole = service.findOne(id);
            ApiPreconditions.assertNotNullOrEmpty(oldRole, "Role not exists: " + id);

            // Update user id
            oldRole.setDescription(role.getDescription());
            oldRole.setName(role.getName());
            oldRole.setActive(role.getActive());
            oldRole.setPermissions(role.getPermissions());

            return ResponseEntity.ok(service.update(oldRole));
        }


        @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE, consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
        @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
        public ResponseEntity<?> delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
            Role oldRole = service.findOne(id);
            ApiPreconditions.assertNotNullOrEmpty(oldRole, "Role not exists: " + id);

            // Delete the user
            service.delete(oldRole);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(oldRole);
        }
    }
```

**RoleRepository**

```
@Repository
public interface RoleRepository extends ExtendedCrudRepository<Role, Long> {

    Set<Role> findByUsersAndActive(User user, Boolean active);

    Role findByName(String name);

}
```

**RoleService:**

```
@Service
public class RoleService {

    private RoleRepository repository;
    private PermissionService permissionService;

    @Autowired
    public RoleService(RoleRepository repository, PermissionService permissionService) {
        this.repository = repository;
        this.permissionService = permissionService;
    }

    public Set<Role> findActiveRolesForUser(User user) {
        Set<Role> roles = repository.findByUsersAndActive(user, true);
        if (roles != null && roles.size() > 0) {
            Set<Permission> permissions;
            for (Role role : roles) {
                permissions = permissionService.findActivePermissionForRole(role);
                role.setPermissions(permissions != null ? permissions : new HashSet<>());
            }
        }

        return roles;
    }


    public Role findOne(Long id) {
        return repository.getOne(id);
    }

    public Page<Role> findAll(Specification specification, Pageable pageable) {
        return getRepository().findAll(specification, pageable);
    }

    public RoleRepository getRepository() {
        return repository;
    }

    public Role create(Role role) {
        return repository.save(role);
    }

    public Role update(Role oldRole) {
        this.repository.save(oldRole);

        return oldRole;
    }

    public void delete(Role oldRole) {

    }
}
```

I would appreciate if you can help me find the issue :). If you need more details please let me know.

**Edit:** I will also add ExtendedCrudRepository

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedCrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    User findOne(Long id);

    void deleteById(User oldUser);


}
```

**Edit 2:** I will add Stacktrace since the error begins:

```
2018-03-28 16:25:18.252  INFO 9330 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@77d0dbba'
2018-03-28 16:25:18.255  INFO 9330 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-03-28 16:25:19.182  WARN 9330 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleController' defined in file [/home/john/Documents/Projects/lottery-api/target/classes/io/sunbits/lotteryapi/resources/RoleController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleService' defined in file [/home/john/Documents/Projects/lottery-api/target/classes/io/sunbits/lotteryapi/services/RoleService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object io.sunbits.lotteryapi.data.repository.ExtendedCrudRepository.findOne(java.io.Serializable)! No property findOne found for type Role!
2018-03-28 16:25:19.183  INFO 9330 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-03-28 16:25:19.184  INFO 9330 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2018-03-28 16:25:19.205  INFO 9330 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2018-03-28 16:25:19.206  INFO 9330 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-03-28 16:25:19.230  INFO 9330 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-03-28 16:25:19.235 ERROR 9330 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleController' defined in file [/home/john/Documents/Projects/lottery-api/target/classes/io/sunbits/lotteryapi/resources/RoleController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleService' defined in file [/home/john/Documents/Projects/lottery-api/target/classes/io/sunbits/lotteryapi/services/RoleService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object io.sunbits.lotteryapi.data.repository.ExtendedCrudRepository.findOne(java.io.Serializable)! No property findOne found for type Role!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at io.sunbits.lotteryapi.LotteryapiApplication.main(LotteryapiApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'roleService' defined in file [/home/john/Documents/Projects/lottery-api/target/classes/io/sunbits/lotteryapi/services/RoleService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object io.sunbits.lotteryapi.data.repository.ExtendedCrudRepository.findOne(java.io.Serializable)! No property findOne found for type Role!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'roleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object io.sunbits.lotteryapi.data.repository.ExtendedCrudRepository.findOne(java.io.Serializable)! No property findOne found for type Role!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.lang.Object io.sunbits.lotteryapi.data.repository.ExtendedCrudRepository.findOne(java.io.Serializable)! No property findOne found for type Role!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findOne found for type Role!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:90) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:350) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:330) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:283) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:265) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:248) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:93) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 70 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:40479', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you post `ExtendedCrudRepository`?

Comment: @NoRepositoryBean
public interface ExtendedCrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>,
        JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {

    User findOne(Long id);

    void deleteById(User oldUser);

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `ExtendCrudRepository`.  You're trying to return a `User` for `findOne(Long id)`,  it should probably return type `T` since `ExtendedCrudRepository` is a generic interface.

When Spring Data tries to create the query for `findOne()` for the `RoleRepository` it's expecting to return a `Role` but you've harded coded a `User` as a return type.

```
@NoRepositoryBean 
public interface ExtendedCrudRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends 
        JpaRepository<T, ID>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> { 

    // You were returning a User here when it should return T
    // Also it should take type ID
    T findById(ID id); 

    // You were accepting a User here as a Id parameter when should
    // be type ID since it is generic.
    void deleteById(ID id);

}
```

> [CrudRepository Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html)

---

#### Update

Spring Data has changed naming scheme for `CrudRepository`

```
interface CrudRepository<T, ID> {

    <S extends T> … save(S entity);
    // Previously save(Iterable)
    <S extends T> … saveAll(Iterable<S> entities);

    // Previously findOne(ID)
    … findById(ID id);

    // Previously exists(…)
    … existsById(ID id);

    … findAll();
    … findAllByIds(Iterable<ID> ids);

    … count();

    // Previously delete(ID)
    … deleteById(ID id);
    … delete(T entity);

    // Previously delete(Iterable)
    … deleteAll(Iterable<? extends T> entities);
    … deleteAll();
}
```

> https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-944

Comment: `T findOne(Long id)` should be `T findOne(ID id)` also, I made changes.  You can try cleaning the project after

Comment: Still not working, and I cleaned my project as well. I believe you are right in your assumption but there should be another thing we are missing.

Comment: Did the stacktrace change at all after making those changes?

Comment: No, still the same results.

Comment: can you add the whole stacktrace that's being printed

Comment: It looks like `findOne` was replaced by `findById` in Spring Data.  Alter the method name to that.